# Fast algorithm to remove stray pixels from images with PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, algorithm, math, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

I need to remove lonely/stray pixels from dynamically generated images, that is, pixels that don't belong to any shape of more than 4 pixels in width/height, this is image is just an example, a merelly illustrative one but the problem is the same.

[image]

As you can see, i have a lot of "stray pixels" that i need to remove from my images, each of those black dots that don't belong to the shape in the center are 1px each, and sometimes there are two black pixels together or more, like this

[image]

Now, imagine we are checking a pixel and we have this: (pixel we are checking is always 5)

[image]

I need to make 5 white, because 2 and 6 are not connected.

So, for example in this case:

[image]

it shouldn't make 5 white because there are 3 pixels next to it.

I think that would do it, dont you?

My algorithm so far is very inefficient, i'm checking huge images and i need to do it fast, here's how it looks so far (pseudocode)

```
# all pixels in the image
for x in range(image_width):
    for y in range(image_height):

        # all 8 pixels surrounding the pixel we are stepped into
        for r in range (x -1, x + 1) and k in range (y -1, y + 1)):
            if pixel[r, k] is black:
               black_pixels += 1
               if black_pixels > 2:
                  #make it white
                  pixel[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
                  #stop
                  break
```

Haven't tested the code but it should kind of work, although this is probably going to be too slow for what i need, i need a fast algorithm that can remove stray pixels from my image, as in [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: [This paper describes a fast 2D median filtering algorithm.](https://nomis80.org/ctmf.pdf) It doesn't do exactly what you asked for, but would at least be a good starting point.

Comment: One way to speed things up is to verify that `pixel[x,y] is black` before running the `r,k` loop. Another way to speed things up is to use a language that's actually designed to be fast. (Also note that the count of `black_pixels` includes `pixel[x,y]`, which affects the `if` statement).

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the algorithm.  Suppose in the first of the 9-pixel diagrams, there is another column, with the top middle pixel black and the top and bottom ones white.  Now pixel 6 is adjacent to 3 black pixels, so it should be retained.  But before we check 6, 5 has been turned white, and now pixel 6 is adjacent to only 2 black pixels.  You'll need a copy of the image to modify if you do it this way, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @saulspatz that's why i'm asking for a better one, got any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @Gazta Do you have to do exactly what you describe, or are you simply trying to clean up the image?  I just had a thought.  Suppose you scale the image down by 50% (or whatever turns out to work well).  The resizing algorithm ought to get rid of a lot of the stray pixels, and when you scale it back to the original size, you ought to have a cleaner image.  Another thought is to try some of the filters in the GIMP and see if they produce the effect you want.  If neither of these ideas work for you, can you give more details about your image format?

Comment: i already solved the algorithm, might post the answer if i have time later, thank you anyways.